# Rope strength necessary to stop a fall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, material-science, string

Just a random thought experiment, that got me confused.

So when you buy a rope you get info about Tensile Strength(lbs) or kg let's say 1000kg.

That means it can hold an object of that mass.

But the object is stationary and I would like to calculate it for a falling object.

So let's say we have a 10kg object that falls, it was falling for 1s without drag so the speed is 1g *1s = 9.8m/s.

### What's the Tensile Strength necessary how to calculate it?

First I was thinking convert it into force F =am but if a = g that would mean that the force is not proportional to speed. And that doesn't feel ok.

We could probably do something with Kinetic energy as it is E=(v^2m)/2 so it scales with v and m. But I don't know what.

My physics is a bit rusty I'm years out of college.

Comment: 'What's the Tensile Strength necessary' -- asked like that, it's not an easy question because nice and simple Hookean elastic model fails far before the breaking point of a rope is reached. So, what could be calculated is the maximum _Impact Force_ of an elastic rope required to stop the falling body. And that impact force must be much much less than Tensile Strength, for the assumptions of linear elasticity to stay valid.

Answer (score 6):

your problem is the bungee jumping problem

you jump from a clip with a rope of  a length
$~L~$  and stiffens $~k~$ .

what is the maximum of the rope tension ?

you have two cases

**I)**

free falling case until your height $~y_I~$ is less the the  rope length $~L~$

$$y_I=\frac g2\,t^2\quad, v=g\,t$$

from here with

$$y_I=L\quad\Rightarrow~ t_L=\frac{\sqrt{2gL}}{g}\quad, v_L=g\,t_L=\sqrt{2gL}$$

**II)**

now the elasticity ($~k~$)  of the rope  is active , you obtain this equation:

$$ m\ddot y(t)=F=m\,g-k\, y(t)$$

You can solve this differential equation with the initial conditions $~y(0)=0~,\dot y(0)=v_L~$ analytically and obtain  the force  $~F(t)~$. From here the maximal force $~F_m~$ is

$$F_m = mg \sqrt{1 + \frac {2kL}{mg}}\\
F_m(k=0)=m\,g
$$

---

with $~k=\frac{E\,A}{L}~$ and
$~A=\pi\left(\frac d2\right)^2~$

$$F_m = mg\, \sqrt{1 + \frac {E\,\pi\,d^2}{2\,mg}}\\
\tag 2$$

where $~E~$ is the (tensile) elastic modulus.

your question

If you buy a rope you know the maximal allowable  weight ($\;[kg]~$)  that it can carry out, you can measure the  diameter $~d~$  and you can find out  the elastic modulus $~E~$ . with these data  applied equation (2) and obtain $~\frac{F_m}{g}~[kg]$ . if the result (with margin ) is less then the maximal allowable weight you can use this rope ,otherwise you can't.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why "1/2" in F = m*g - k*y(t)/2 ? If that second force came from Hooke's law, then shouldn't it be simply "k*y(t)" ?

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by making the point which addresses OP's question directly: **the tensile strength of the rope is not enough information** to determine whether it can stop a falling object, even provided the parameters of the fall. A variety of ropes with the same tensile strength may have different stiffnesses, meaning some will snap while others won't. The only universal statement one can make is the obvious fact that the tensile strength must be at least the object's weight (your $k \to 0$ limit, wherein the rope is very stretchy, so the fall is stopped gradually).

Comment: @IgorG this is correct  $~F=k\,y~$

Comment: To expand on jawheele's comment: This is very important for designing climbing ropes. In multi-pitch lead climbing there are situations where the lead climber can fall twice the length of the amount of rope between climber and belay point plus the stretch of the rope  – now you have the design constraint that the force on the climber mustn't be too high (so the rope mustn't be too stiff), but at the same time the stretch mustn't be too big (as this means a longer fall, potentially into a ledge leading to injury, also if the rope is extremely springy it will have reduced breaking strength).

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the equation $F=ma$ the acceleration is due to the stopped fall, not what the body was going through before the fall. Say the rope stopped a body falling with velocity $v$ in $t$ time (stopping times may differ due to elasticity of the rope, and maybe other factors that I don't know of) then the average acceleration $a=\frac{v}{t}$.
But then again average acceleration is of limited use in this case. You'd want to know the highest instantaneous acceleration and compare it to the limit of the rope.
Another way would be to find the maximum extension in the rope. The Young's modulus is defined as $$Y=\frac{Fl}{A\Delta l}$$
Now for a rope $A$ and $l$ are constant (roughly). So we can rewrite this as $$F=k\Delta l$$
Add a negative to account for the direction, and you have a spring!
With the maximum mass the rope can withstand $F$ and the constant $k$ which can be experimentally found, we can calculate $\Delta L$ the maxmimum extension in the rope before it snaps. 
Then we equate the kinetic energy of the falling body with the potential energy in the rope at maximum extension.
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}k(\Delta L)^2\\
\implies v=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}\Delta L$$

I may have overlooked something, so feel free to correct me. Also don't go buying safety ropes just based off of this answer.